# How to use regular expression to trim the beginning of a line to a specific symbol?

Tags: javascript, regex

They send me a text file that starts with unnecessary information and then what is needed goes further. How to remove the beginning to a specific symbol.

Example: line = 'lots of text {text needed}';

It is necessary to delete everything before the symbol {. I tried the regular expression option below:

```
let str = /^[^{]+/.exec(line)[0];
```

but it returns the beginning of the text to the symbol {
I need to do the opposite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you can do with JavaScript.

```js
var str = 'lots of text {text needed}';
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("{") + 1);
console.log(str);
```